# Use Embed API to embed Google Analytics location map view

Tags: google-analytics, embed

THe below is a screenshot of a view on the Google analytics website (Geo > Location > Primary Dimension = city)

I would like to embed this exact view or replicate it as similarly as possible using google's Embed API and display it on my own site.

I have followed the tutorial here > https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide and got the simple line graph working on my site but I cant seem to find any information showing how to add the map functionallity, the pie chart, or the table like we see in the below.

**Are there any good examples or tutorials that could help me with this?**

I tried the documentation but I just dont see a lot of explanation regarding what you can create with the API.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this?
http://jsbin.com/relufutenuto/2/edit

You can set chart options based on the options allowed by the various Google chart libraries. Here's the Google chart documentation for the chart type GEO:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options

**Note:** you might have to disable pop-up blockers to get auth to work in jsbin, but this should give you the idea.

Here's the part of the code that sets the chart type of options:

```
var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
  query: {
    'ids': 'ga:1234',
    'dimensions': 'ga:country',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'GEO',
    container: 'timeline',
    options: {
      region: '155', // Western Europe
      displayMode: 'markers'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew there had to be more documentation on these features somewhere.