# I want retrieve from my google analytics account map show traffic by country?

Tags: php, google-analytics, geolocation, maps

I'm working on web app (php codeigniter framework) and want to build custom user dashboard,I'm already use embed API and I was retrieve basic charts and also real time API is used and I got active users,
Now I want to get map from my Google analytics account that shown the traffic on user profile by country?

Is that way to do that ??

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Embed API to embed Google Analytics location map view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944787/use-embed-api-to-embed-google-analytics-location-map-view)

Comment: Thanks to share answered question that was helpful