# Google Analytics Embed API location view with secondary dimension

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to achieve the same thing as described in here:

[Use Embed API to embed Google Analytics location map view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944787/use-embed-api-to-embed-google-analytics-location-map-view)

but I`m also interested in getting the secondary dimension (i.e. the table underneath the map).

Any snippets for fiddling with ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create another `DataChart` object and include that in your visualisation. For example:

```
var dataTable = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
  query: {
    'ids': 'ga:1234',
    'dimensions': 'ga:country',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'TABLE',
    container: 'data-table'
  }
});
```